# MDL-Menu bottom right offscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

Hi I am trying to get the following code to show on the right side of the nav-bar however when I do it is only showing half (in other words half the menu is right:-32px; - I have not added any CSS this is the default material design lite code).

---

---

THE ERROR IS IN MY CSS
https://codepen.io/russellharrower/pen/RgMJaR

My core getmdl

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getmdl.io/assets/components.css">
<script src="https://getmdl.io/assets/components.js"></script>
<script src="//code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

HTML CODE

```
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <!-- Title -->
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">SITE</span></span>
                <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="fixed-header-drawer-exp" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <!-- MDL bottom right Aligned Menu Button -->  
             <button id="my-menu-bottom-right"
                    class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
              <i class="material-icons">share</i>
            </button>

            <!-- Menu items List , mdl-menu--bottom-right -->

            <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
                for="my-menu-bottom-right">
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">Facebook</li>
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">Twitter</li>
              <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Google Plus</li>
            </ul>

            </div>

        </header>
```

[image: mdl-menu]

here is the CSS that gets generated automatically I am not sure what code generates this or why.

```
element.style {
    right: -35.1563px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

---

error was

```
.mdl-textfield{width:100% !important;}
```

so I need to style it but NOT give it a global .mdl-textfield (otherwise it screws everything up so #id of div before that)

Answer (score 0):

`mdl-menu--bottom-left` to `mdl-menu--bottom-right` in menu `ul`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wemXBe

```
<header class="mdl-layout__header">

            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <!-- Title -->
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">SITE</span></span>
                <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="fixed-header-drawer-exp" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <!-- MDL bottom right Aligned Menu Button -->  
                 <button id="my-menu-bottom-left"
                        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
                  <i class="material-icons">share</i>
                </button>

                <!-- Menu items List , mdl-menu--bottom-right -->
                <!-- mdl-menu--bottom-left to mdl-menu--bottom-right  -->
                <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
                    for="my-menu-bottom-left">
                  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Facebook</li>
                  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Twitter</li>
                  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Google Plus</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </header>
```

Comment: please explain what you changed? because that did not work (and very unclear) - note I am using 1.3.0 MDL

Comment: Once you change the left button to right side, you forgot to change the menu class. The answer is already inside your question.

Comment: Ok your code works - I found the error it's in my CSS style .css file i'll codepen it

Comment: found the error (/*STATUS AREA*/
.status-dialog{width:980px !important;}
.mdl-textfield{width:100% !important;})